# How to consume Nuget package from private Github Package Registry

Tags: github-actions, github-package-registry

To start with, I am using private repos in Github. I managed to publish a `nuget` package to Github packages.

I can reference that too in my code using `nuget.config`. Following is my config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <clear />
    <add key="Nuget" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="ThingMZing" value="https://nuget.pkg.github.com/ORG_NAME/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
  <packageSourceCredentials>
    <ThingMZing>
      <add key="Username" value="%GITHUB_USER_NAME%"/>
      <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="%GITHUB_PAT%"/>
    </ThingMZing>
  </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

I have majority of libraries being referenced from Nuget and only one from my private GPR. This is working fine in local development environment.

When I am trying to configure Github Actions, I have problem restoring package from my GPR. Following is my yaml for actions:

```
runs-on: windows-latest
    env:
      GITHUB_USER_NAME: ${{secrets.USER_NAME}}
      GITHUB_PAT: ${{secrets.HUB_PAT}}

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Setup .NET
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
        dotnet-version: 5.0.x
    - name: Restore dependencies
      run: dotnet restore
```

I am getting following error:

```
Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source ''https://nuget.pkg.github.com/ORG_NAME/download/MY_LIBRARY/index.json''.
  Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
```

For all libraries (Nuget and GPR), github actions is trying to hit GPR and it is not attempting to resolve them in Nuget. One library that is in GPR, is also getting `Unauthorized` despite trying `PAT` and `GITHUB_TOKEN`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: did you solve this problem? I am having the same issue.

Comment: Any solutions to this?